# Create directory on SQL Server on image upload

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload

I want to store each individual image into it's own directory which will be created on upload action with following structure

```
/server_img_path/<year>/<month>/<day>/<hour><minutes><seconds><img_id>.png
```

Now I have following which works but with upload storage of one directory

```
var fn = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/" + name + ".png");
img.Save(fn, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how popular your web site is/will be but using filenames with only a 1 second resolution will result in duplicate filenames when you have multiple uploads at the same time. If you are storing a link to the image in a DB when they are uploaded it might be better to assign a unique name from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This for saving images, but this will not store each individual image into it's own directory, because by this code you will be able to create a directory for a day. so all images for a day will go in that folder.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var fn = Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/");
var dirPath = Path.Combine(fn, now.Year.ToString(), now.Month.ToString(), now.Day.ToString());
if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
var filename = dirPath+now.Hour.ToString() + now.Minute.ToString() + now.Second.ToString() + name  + ".png";
img.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```